# Comparing an object with a String using equals() method

Tags: java, language-features, comparison

In the below example, I am expecting `equals()` to return `true`:

```
public class flower {
    String flower;
    public flower (String flower) {
        this.flower = flower;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        flower one = new flower("Flower");
        boolean isSame = false;
        if(one.equals("Flower")) {
            isSame = true;
        }
        System.out.print(isSame);
    }
}
```

However, the result I get is `false`... is it because I'm comparing an object with a `String`? I read the `equals()` method and is said to compare `String`s with `Objects`. Why am I getting the result as `false` although they are the same?

Comment: Look at the implementation of `equals()` which is defined in the Object class.

Comment: They are **not** the same. They're not even the same class. One has an attribute with a value that is *equal* to the other (but not the same). That is nowhere near close enough to satisfy `equals()`.

Comment: This is my car. (Imagine an Opel Corsa.)  This is a Pirelli PT-1004 tyre.  (Imagine a Pirelli PT-1004 tyre.)  My car is ***most definitely not equal*** to the tyre, even though my car does in fact happen to be wearing Pirelli PT-1004 tyres.  It won't be equal even if you steal 3 of my tyres and leave me with only one.  It won't. Ever. Be equal. To a tyre.

Comment: why didn't you ask at Stack Overflow, are you [question blocked](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7020/31260) there? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: @MikeNakis: "It won't. Ever. Be equal. To a tyre." It will if your car and tire define `equals()` so they can be equal to each other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer: You need to override the implementation of `equals()` in your `Flower` (note: capital `F`) class. This  will do something you *like* to do:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return (o instanceof Flower && ((Flower)o).flower.equals(flower)) ||
                (o instanceof String && o.equals(flower));
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return flower.hashCode();
}
```

Overriding `hashCode()` together with `equals()` is good form: generally, the 'attributes' (e.g. fields) you pick for doing an `equals()` should be used in your `hashCode()` calculation too. In layman terms, they should 'agree' with each other.

The **big/major/severe** problem, as pointed out by practically everyone here I presume, is that `equals()` is meant to be [*symmetric*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> It is *symmetric*: for any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, `x.equals(y)` should return true if and only if `y.equals(x)` returns true.

And unfortunately for your `Flower` class, `String.equals(Object)` is defined [as such](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> The result is `true` ***if and only if*** the argument is not `null` and is a `String` object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object. (emphasis mine)

This means that no `String` will ever return `true` when you pass a `Flower` object to `equals()`.

Sure, you can still go against the convention, but you'll likely run into bugs - minor or major - very soon when you learn more about the language, e.g. the `Collection` classes.

***Therefore: avoid such comparisons with `equals()`.***

Answer (score 1):

As Killian says you are comparing an Flower object that contains an string attribute, to a string.

If you want to see if the Flower object's name attribute equals the string you need to check the actual strings.

```
one.name.equals("Flower")
```

thought this would be a really bad idea because a Flower object is not a string object, it merely contains a string object, so you aren't comparing like with like.